# Why my MenuItem is not being hidden?

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I am trying to hide a `MenuItem` of my menu but without success.

This is the code that I have right now:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.lastOption);
    item.setVisible(false);

    invalidateOptionsMenu();

    return true;
}
```

but it still shows that option when I run the application.

Trying to find why this behaviour happened, I tried to set some breakpoints to my code and found that `menu` variable has a variable called `mVisibleItems`. In that variable I can see that the item that I tried to hide does not appear. It appears on the application, though.

So, I cannot understand why if it does not appear on the menu visible variables, it still is shown on the application.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater); in retrun

Comment: @SuryaPrakashKushawah on `onCreateOptionsMenu` method?

Comment: @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.lastOption);
    item.setVisible(false);



    return  
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);;
}

Comment: @SuryaPrakashKushawah ... haha good one ... check in documentation what invalidateOptionsMenu causing

Comment: @Raghavendra Yes, I have looked before there and any of the solutions worked for me. It is why I finally have created this another question.

Comment: @Error404 are u re-using the same menu in different activities. If not, and if u haven't tried this already? just for a workaround set visible false in main_menu.xml and enable in activity and comment invalidateOptionsMenu(); try once?

Comment: @Raghavendra Yes, I have tried before to hide it directly on the XML and it hide well but if I try to set `item.setVisible(true)` it does not re-appear in any of both methods (`onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu`)

Comment: @Error404 can u use only onCreateOptionsMenu() set visibility there only and don't use  invalidateOptionsMenu for a workaround and try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that this is not the better way to do this but I could not do it using `onPrepareOptionsMenu`.

As I need two types of menu depending of the user that had logged in (admin or user) I finally do this creating two types of menu for my application. One with some options and one without the options that I do not need for a normal user. Then, on `onCreateOptionsMenu` I inflate the menu that I need depending of the user that has logged in.

This is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    if("admin".equals(typeUser)){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_admin, menu);
    }else{
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_user, menu);
    }

    return true;
}
```

where `typeUser` is a `String` that I send from the `Login Activity` in which I set a bundle depending of the user that has logged in.

I also have created two `activity_main` layouts changing the menu option of the `NavigationView` on the XML:

`app:menu="@menu/activity_main_admin"` or `app:menu="@menu/activity_main_user"`, depending on the layout.

Finally, I also have created a condition to set the layout on the `onCreate` method of `MainActivity` depending of the user that has logged in. This is the code to do this:

```
if("admin".equals(typeUser)){
    setContentView(R.layout.admin);
}else{
    setContentView(R.layout.user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`invalidateOptionsMenu();`, calls `onCreateOptionsMenu` again. From the documentation

> Declare that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. The
>   onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) method will be called the next time it needs
>   to be displayed.

so, after setting your item to false, you are inflating the layout of your menu, again

Comment: Hi @BlackBelt, I know that it calls again `onCreateOptionsMenu` but I thought that after changes I should re-inflate the menu. If I remove that line, the MenuItem is still being shown on the application.

Comment: banally in the same way. You could just set a global flag and when onCreatOptionsMenu is called again you decide depending on the value of this flag if you want do hide or not the menu item

Comment: I tried calling `invalidateOptionsMenu` on my `onCreate` method of my MainActivity class because I need that, depending of the user that has log in inside the application, it shows some options or not of the menu. So I tried also to use `item.setVisible(false);` on my `onCreateOptionsMenu` but it also does not work. But I do not understand why if I inspect it with my debugger it does not have the option on `mVisibleItems` and on the application it has.